# changing one of the values in a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, replace

i am trying to make a linkedlist (abstract data type) and i need to replace one element in in my 2D array.

The parameter x is my data and p is my pointer. I am not able to figure out how to get the index of one element in a list(Third line from the bottom): [('b',1),('n',2)] i tried using .index(1) but it can't find it because i would have to search for it this way: .index('b',1) but once i append the element i don't know the 'b' only the number! I need this index to replace one value in the array(which i can't seem to make work either)(that is th last line).

```
class Linked_list():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Linkedlist = [('b',1),('n',2)]
        self.Index = int

    def InsertionE(self,x,p):
            self.Index = self.Linkedlist.index(p)                                                               
            self.Linkedlist[Index].replace(self.Linkedlist[:,len(self.Linkedlist)])
```

to sum up, my question is:

1 how do i search for a part of 1 element in a 2d array? and

2 how do i replace one part of 1 element in a 2d array?

Answer (score 0):

In a 0-10 scale of how messy is what you are trying there, I'd say it is 11.
I'd suggest you take a look at the item-retrieval-setting methods in the data model - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Then, reading the some info on collections.abc  and implement your class inheriting from `collections.MutableSequence` - if what a sequence does will attend your needs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

Play around in the interactive console. When you are familiar with it, taking a look at the coding style recomendations at the PEP-8 would not be bad - a class name like `Linked_list` which instances contain an attribute named  `LinkedList` will make most Pythonistas' eyes bleed - that is possibly the cause no one has taken care to address you. - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ .

All that said, I still can't figure out what you are trying to do - either overall, with a "linkedlist" or specifically in the `InsertionE` method.

The concept of "linkedlist" itself makes sense in languages where one have to manually control the memory disposition of objects. The Pyhton "list" object, while not a linked list is efficient enough to cover most use cases one would have with linked-lists, but for alogrithms which would require a lots of insertions in the middle of the list. Then, one could create a "linked list" data structure in Python easily by implementing the "collections.abc.MutableSequence" interface and have a "Node" class to hold referencees to previous/next objects.

Also, for real-world 2D data types, you'd likely be much better of using Python's numpy external library. Nothing you'd implement from scratch could get even close in performance and reliability to this project (unless you have enough resources to match 30+ years numeric computing optimizations, of course)

All that said, what I can still say about this code is that te  `.index` method from lists you are trying to use, apparently  to findout the "row address" in your data-structure needs an exact match - so, it would not be able to find anything by the first element of tuples the list contain. But I really can't figure out what it *should* be doing by your description and code in this question to offer any suggestions other than  "pause there, study a bit more of the language, start over". Sorry.

But maybe, depending what you are trying to do there, maybe a plain `dict` could serve you as well - check the possibilities of a `dict` before redoing everything, if you are in a hurry.

Comment: thank you for the comment, I have read over the links you gave me the have helped me get a better understanding.